# Flip animation between two activity

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to do flip animations between two activities?
In the API demos `Transition3d.java class` is there but that is to flip the view and not the activities.

Comment: sorry that is Transition3d.java

Comment: do you want to implement screen transition animation between 2 activities?

Comment: yes sir and actually i have done that. see ans below that helped me

Comment: Can we do image curl between activities... not with images only,

Answer (score 4):

yes it is possible. This example here shows you how to make a 3d flip between activities.

http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher

This example makes use of animation in and animation out, such that it will look like a 3d flip taking place between activities. In the first activity's onResume you will be able to see a "animation out" followed by "animation in" in Activity two.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Android any idea about pagecurl(down curl and up curl in android)

Comment: can we do it between activities instead of changing the images ?
any help is appreciated