# Flip Transition between activities 

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, transition

I'd like to be able to transition between activities using a flip transition that can be achieved on the iphone. is this possible in android between activities?

I need to do it between activities because it seems I cannot toggle the feature action bar from an overlay style to a solid style within one activity.

Comment: I wouldn't touch this with a 10 foot patent attorney.

Comment: hahah I doubt that this is patented :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10481841/1224741